# Добавление файлов в SVN из подпапок по маске

Tags: svn

Eсли указать маску:

```
svn add *.cs
```

Tо в подпапки не лезет.

Пробовал все варианты аргумента `depth`:

```
svn add *.cs --depth=empty --force
svn add *.cs --depth=files --force
svn add *.cs --depth=immediates --force
svn add *.cs --depth=infinity --force
```

Не работает:

```
svn: warning: W155010: 'D:\SvnNetKrv\*.cs' not found
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

Если указать:

```
svn add *
```

Берутся все файлы из всех подпапок.

Почему? Как сделать, чтобы все файлы `*.cs` (и только они, потому что нужен только исходный код) попали в SVN?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести, всё работает.  У вас просто  нет таких файлов, которые попадают под маску '*.cs'.

Comment: @0xdb честно, есть) в исходном директории нет, а в подпапках есть

Comment: Тогда всё правильно, под маску `*.cs` ничего не попадает, у вас же нет подпапок "subdir.cs".  Указывайте подпапки "subdir/*.cs", если их много, то делайте циклом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражение `*.cs` содержит подстановочный символ, который будет замещён до выполнения *svn* комманды, и под который попадают только файлы содержащие в имени `.cs` в текущей папке, а также подпаках содержащих в имени `.cs`, например:

```
.
|-- src.cs
|-- subdir.cs
|   `-- src.cs
```

Под маску `*` попадают все файлы из подпапок потому, что также все подпапки попадают под эту маску.
Укажите подпапки, которые содержат файлы с исходниками, например:

```
svn add src/*.cs src/csfiles/*.cs
```

Замещением подстановочных символов занимается командный интерпретатор, а не выполняемая команда, в данном случае *svn*. Поэтому, какие подстановочные символы - `*, ? [, ]` и т.д. - и как они замещаются, зависит от используемого командного интерпретатора. На обычных ОС - это *sh*, *bash* и им подобные, на других ОС - *CMD*, *PowerShell*, или также *bash* (если установлены *Cygwin*, *MinGW* и т.п.). Не ожидайте одинакового поведенния одной и той же команды, даже на одной системе, если пользуетесь разными интерпретаторами.

Если подпапок с исходниками много, и надо рекурсивно найти все файлы для добавления в svn, то решение зависит также от используемого командного интерпретатора.
Например, в CMD где-то так (в batch-скрипте используйте переменную цикла `%%f`):

```
for /f %f in ('dir /s /b /a *.cs') do svn add  "%f"
```

Comment: отлично подошел пример с циклом

Comment: Значит угадал, что предложить для примера, а то в вопросе явно не указано какая оболочка. Так можно только первый раз делать, потом будет ругаться, что уже есть в репозотории.

Comment: поправьте ответ для CMD для потомков, ваша строчка не взлетела, вот эта заработала: for /f %%f in ('dir /s /b /a *.cs') do svn add "%f%"
НЕТ НЕ ЗАРАБОТАЛА

Comment: вот эта пошла for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a *.cs') do svn add "%%i"

Comment: Спасибо за замечание.   Вы можете поправить? Я приму, а то не сподручно с телефона.

Comment: не, кармы навеное не хватает. позже поправьте)

Comment: @vvsibir Я попробовал, всё правильно, для скрипта `.bat`  нужно %%f, а просто в коммандной строке одиночный % . Но всё равно правку внесу.